# Sroll View Not Scrolling Up in Fragments Using the New Navigation Architecture Components

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a fragment that i have navigated to it using the modern Navigation UI. The problem am having is that the scroll view wont start scrolling unless the view is long. That's okay and i understand but it arises a problem where the Edit text inputs that are the bottom of the screen are being hidden when the keyboard is opened hence you can't see when you are keying in hence the reason for needing a scroll view to scroll down so that the view can be scrolled up above the keyboard

Is there a way to initiate the scroll view so that when the keyboard hides the Edit text input, i can still be able to scroll up and see what am keying in

My Navigation Host Fragment

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"/>
```

My Fragment layout that has a scroll view and that its not scrolling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ScrollFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Second Name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="country"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="province"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="County"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="province"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="region"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="village"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If i add more view and the layout is long enough the scroll view is just working fine but its not scrolling when the views have not reached the bottom yet keyboard is hiding the view and i cant be able to see what am typing on the edit text

I have tried using Nested Scroll View and setting the

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

but its still not working.

I have also tried setting the following properties to the scroll view

```
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: have you got the solution for the above issue?

Comment: I just added space <Space
            android:id="@+id/space"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login" />